# How to inject js in shortcode

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm quite new to web development and Wordpress. I'm trying to create a plugin. A plugin task is to register a shortcode and inject inside it a js script. 
First I'm adding script and then register shortcode.
in my my-custom-plugin.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_functions');

function my_functions()
{
    wp_enqueue_scripts('my-script-1', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}


register_shortcode();
function register_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode('roomservice', 'shortcodeHTML');
}

function shortcodeHTML()
{
    return '<div class="container-5"><div><input type="text" onClick="clickable"></div><div><input type="text"></div><div><input type="text"></div><div><input type="text"></div></div>';
}
```

myscript.js

```
function clickable() {
  console.log('clickable')

}
```

I get this error:

> Notice: wp_script_is was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should
>   not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts,
>   admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see
>   Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
>   in version 3.3.0.) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4161
>   Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes
>   exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/wp-includes/cache.php on line 530
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 262144 bytes) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/wp-includes/load.php on line 679

Comment: @James it was my error, script still not enqueued, i have update my question

Comment: still showing the original error message